# WORKING QMAIL TOASTER - QMAIL, VPOPMAIL, DOVECOT AND ROUNDCUBE

Tags: dovecot, roundcube, qmail

Am on an Amazon AWS EC2 Linux AMI Server. I used "**Bill's Linux Qmail Toaster v. 0.9.4**" at [Bill's Linux Qmail Toaster v. 0.9.4](http://billslinuxqmail.sourceforge.net/toaster/) to install the various software packages there, specifically:  daemontools, ucspi-tcp, qmail, vpopmail, dovecot, squirrel mail, autorespond, ezmlm-idx and qmailadmin. Qmail, Vpopmail and Dovecot are all working well, having tested as below...

Testing SMTP using `telnet localhost 25` has no errors.

Testing IMAP using `telnet localhost 143` has no errors.

Testing POP3 using `telnet localhost 110` has no errors.

**Question #1**
Attempting to use squirrel mail brought the frontend error "*ERROR: Connection dropped by IMAP server.*" which I couldn't figure where to check for error log(s). Someone please help. **Where do I check to understand this error and fix it?**

**Question #2**
I installed roundcube after squirrel mail failed. I followed the approach at [RoundCube Installation](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/wiki/Installation). Attempting to login with roundcube shows no frontend error but does not login either. When I survey the **roundcube/config/config.inc.php** I find only the following basic settings...

```
$config = array();
$config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysqli://acc:passwd@localhost/roundcube';
$config['default_host'] = 'localhost';
$config['smtp_server'] = 'localhost';
$config['smtp_port'] = 25;
$config['smtp_user'] = '%u';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';
$config['support_url'] = '';
$config['product_name'] = 'Roundcube Webmail';
$config['des_key'] = 'some_des_key';
$config['plugins'] = array(
    'archive',
    'zipdownload',
);
$config['skin'] = 'larry';
```

**Are these settings essential for a successful roundcube setup?**

**Question #3**
When I investigate dovecot.conf, which I got after applying the exact steps at [Dovecot Installation](http://billslinuxqmail.sourceforge.net/toaster/?page=dovecot) I see that almost all options and paths are actually commented out, for instance:

- base_dir = /var/run/dovecot/
- login_dir = /var/run/dovecot/login
- login_executable = /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/imap-login
- mail_executable = /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/imap
- ...
- login_executable = /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/pop3-login
- mail_executable = /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/pop3
- auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
- ...
- auth_executable = /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-auth
- ...

I haven't tried uncommenting because some like */var/run/dovecot/auth-master* do not even seem to exist on my system.

**Is this configuration file with such (apparent mistakes) usual and usable?**

Comment: http://billslinuxqmail.sourceforge.net/toaster/?page=vpopmail also instructs to install backend using "...src/vpopmail-5.4.32/backends/cdb/" which doesn't exist in the source code... Who will help pls???